# How can I idiomatically and efficiently consume a Pipe in some non-IO monad, with an IO action?

Tags: haskell, haskell-pipes

I have a `Producer` that creates values that depend on randomness, using my own `Random` monad:

```
policies :: Producer (Policy s a) Random x
```

`Random` is a wrapper over `mwc-random` that can be run from `ST` or `IO`:

```
newtype Random a =
  Random (forall m. PrimMonad m => Gen (PrimState m) -> m a)

runIO :: Random a -> IO a
runIO (Random r) = MWC.withSystemRandom (r @ IO)
```

The `policies` producer yields better and better policies from a simple reinforcement learning algorithm.

I can efficiently plot the policy after, say, 5,000,000 iterations by indexing into `policies`:

```
Just convergedPolicy <- Random.runIO $ Pipes.index 5000000 policies
plotPolicy convergedPolicy "policy.svg"
```

I now want to plot the intermediate policies on every 500,000 steps to see how they converge. I wrote a couple of functions that take the `policies` producer and extract a list (`[Policy s a]`) of, say, 10 policies—one every 500,000 iterations—and then plot all of them.

However, these functions take far longer (10x) and use more memory (4x) than just plotting the final policy as above, even though the total number of learning iterations should be the same (ie 5,000,000). I suspect that this is due to extracting a list inhibiting the garbage collector, and this seems to be an unidiomatic use of Pipes:

> Idiomatic pipes style consumes the elements immediately as they are generated instead of loading all elements into memory.

What's the correct approach to consuming a pipe like this when the `Producer` is over some random monad (ie `Random`) and the effect I want to produce is in `IO`?

Put another way, I want to plug a `Producer (Policy s a) Random x` into a `Consumer (Policy s a) IO x`.

Comment: Does `Random` have a `MonadIO` instance? If so, you will have `hoist liftIO  ::  Consumer (Policy s a) IO x -> Consumer (Policy s a) Random x` . There are other ways of going about this, some might be faster, but it might help to know more about `Random`.

Comment: @Michael: It doesn't, and I don't want it to. It can only do randomness and *not* general IO. Ideally, I'd love a solution that only depends on the fact that `Random` has a `runIO :: Random a -> IO a` function.

Comment: And I guess you don't want `hoist runIO` to convert the `Producer (Policy s a) Random x` into a `Producer (Policy s a) IO x` because of the way randomness is generated.

Comment: I am thinking about the last sentence in saying these things.  Some sort of fold might be the fastest thing, but might require being clearer on what the ultimate effect desired is.

Comment: @Michael: Honestly, I'm not sure. Part of the problem is that my mental model for exactly how the randomness is run is pretty weak! Having a function that uses `hoist runIO` internally to get a `Producer (Policy s a) IO x` before plugging it into a consumer seems fine—let me give it a try.

Comment: The answer to this question lies in the definition of `Random` which isn't included in the question. You do not want to `hoist runIO`, `runIO` will be invoked many more times than you can possibly imagine resulting in the creation of numerous generators.

Comment: @Cirdec: Yeah, good point. I'll add the definition of `Random`.

Comment: Oh I see the type declaration now. Why not just use `type Random m = ReaderT (Gen (PrimState m)) m` or something like that, rather than wrapping a rank 2 type?   Then the correct handling with pipes becomes obvious from the pipes API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Random` is a reader that reads a generator

```
import Control.Monad.Primitive
import System.Random.MWC

newtype Random a = Random {
    runRandom :: forall m. PrimMonad m => Gen (PrimState m) -> m a
}
```

We can trivially convert a `Random a` into a `ReaderT (Gen (PrimState m)) m a`. This *trivial* operation is the one you want to `hoist` to turn a `Producer ... Random a` into a `Producer ... IO a`.

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Reader

toReader :: PrimMonad m => Random a -> ReaderT (Gen (PrimState m)) m a
toReader = ReaderT . runRandom
```

Since `toReader` is trivial there won't be any random generation overhead from `hoist`ing it. This function is written just to demonstrate its type signature.

```
import Pipes

hoistToReader :: PrimMonad m => Proxy a a' b b' Random                          r ->
                                Proxy a a' b b' (ReaderT (Gen (PrimState m)) m) r
hoistToReader = hoist toReader
```

There are two approaches to take here. The simple approach is to `hoist` your `Consumer` into the same monad, compose the pipes together, and run them.

```
type ReadGenIO = ReaderT GenIO IO

toReadGenIO :: MFunctor t => t Random a -> t ReadGenIO a
toReadGenIO = hoist toReader

int :: Random Int
int = Random uniform

ints :: Producer Int Random x
ints = forever $ do
    i <- lift int
    yield i

sample :: Show a => Int -> Consumer a IO ()
sample 0 = return ()
sample n = do
    x <- await
    lift $ print x
    sample (n-1)

sampleSomeInts :: Effect ReadGenIO ()
sampleSomeInts = hoist toReader ints >-> hoist lift (sample 1000)

runReadGenE :: Effect ReadGenIO a -> IO a
runReadGenE = withSystemRandom . runReaderT . runEffect

example :: IO ()
example = runReadGenE sampleSomeInts
```

---

There's another set of tools in `Pipes.Lift` that users of pipes should be aware of. These are the tools for running transformers like your `Random` monad by distributing it over a `Proxy`. There are pre-built tools here for running the familiar transformers from the transformers library. They are all built out of [`distribute`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes/docs/Pipes-Lift.html#v:distribute). It turns a `Proxy ... (t m) a` into a `t (Proxy ... m) a` which you can run *once* with whatever tools you use to run a `t`.

```
import Pipes.Lift

runRandomP :: PrimMonad m => Proxy a a' b b' Random r ->
                             Gen (PrimState m) -> Proxy a a' b b' m r
runRandomP = runReaderT . distribute . hoist toReader
```

You can finish combining the pipes together and use `runEffect` to get rid of the `Proxy`s, but you'd be juggling the generator argument yourself as you combine the `Proxy ... IO r`s together.

Comment: Just got around to implementing this, and I definitely like this solution. Thanks!